# Eclipse is not detecting servlet libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am building a dynamic web project using eclipse j2ee helios 3 version. Everything was working fine..but suddenly one day, when I opened the eclipse, all the ear and jre libraries which was visible in project explorer were gone. And after that I had to put all the libraries related to it manually inside workspace of eclipse/projects folder/web inf/ lib. I did put the servlet-api.jar inside the lib folder of the project, but it was giving me some validate jar error. So, I removed it from the lib folder, but now when i am trying to run the servlet run as-> run on server, I am getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message 

description The requested resource () is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/6.0.30
```

and the url is weird too:

http://localhost:8080/cPEP_UI/WEB-INF/classes/Engine_rurl_delete.java

any ideas guys?!

Comment: Try changing your question title to be more descriptive; make it stand out to Eclipse users who've experienced this very issue & you're likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage the dynamic web project facets by *Rightclick project > Properties > Project Facets*. At least Dynamic Web Module and Java must be checked. You can manage the dynamic web project targeted runtime (which contains the necessary libraries) by *Rightclick project > Properties > Targeted Runtime*. At least one server must be associated. You should above all **not** put servletcontainer specific libraries in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. This is not the right way to do.

If in vain or you don't understand the undercovers meaning/working of those, I'd suggest to backup the code, throw away the project and create a new one. And then be careful with project properties/settings.

Comment: Ya, I know that. But the problem with mine is...I had all the library structure automatically created by eclipse in my project explorer. But suddenly one day..all the libraries were gone. Dont know what happened. I just want to retain that. and one more thing...Even If I am creating a new dynamic web project, the servlet is not being recognized in it too.

Comment: Aren't you just looking at a different view? Eclipse has two general views of the file structure: Project Explorer (Java oriented) and Navigator (filesystem oriented). You can switch between them by clicking the top tabs. As to the unrecognized servlet, you have to be more specific in describing the problem. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Ok... my eclipse is not able to recognize the HttpSerlvetResponse class too. It is not able to recognize servlet at all. JSP is running fine though.

Comment: Then the targeted runtime is not properly set. Reread the 3rd sentence of the 1st paragraph of the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. In the future don't comment too fast with "Ya, I know that" :) You didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://localhost:8080/cPEP_UI/WEB-INF/classes/Engine_rurl_delete.java
```

`WEB-INF` isn't standard public web space you can't access it this way, So 404

Comment: Ya, I know that. I didnt create that URL, it was created when I right click the file then run as->run on server.and problem with mine is...I had all the library structure automatically created by eclipse in my project explorer. But suddenly one day..all the libraries were gone. Dont know what happened. I just want to retain that. and one more thing...Even If I am creating a new dynamic web project, the servlet is not being recognized in it too.