# eclipse requested resource not available

Tags: eclipse

I have run a j2ee application in tomcat/eclipse for several months now, but suddenly (after working with changed in the css files), I get the server error:
The requested resource /appname/ is not available. I'm totally lost. I've gone through a number of posts. This one describes my problem: [Eclipse is not detecting servlet libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615533/eclipse-is-not-detecting-servlet-libraries), but I've gone through everything in that post without finding any missing jars or servers or anything in my project.

I'm running Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Helios Service Release 1.

```
Project -> Properties -> Server shows Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost
Project -> Build path, please see attached screen dump.
Project -> Project Facets: Dynamic Web Module 2.5 and Java 1.6 is checked.
```

I have tried to clean and rebuild the project.

I'm running over https so I'm connecting to https://localhost:8443/appname/Start. I'm not sure if that could be the problem, but it has worked ok until now.

Can anyone give me a hint what can be wrong?

Finally got it working again, but I honestly don't know exactly what fixed it.

I started with removing some servlets/servlet mappings from the web.xml file. After having done that change, when restarting the server, the Start servlet was found, but the jsp that the servlet was forwaring to was not (and the url to the jsp page looked strange). Also the logcat property file was not found. I read in another post that the Server might need to be cleaned so I did that and then cleaned the project once again. Then restarted the Server and now it's the application is running again.

Thanks for your help anyway, Andrei.

Comment: Can you show us the Tomcat log at deployment time? (Should be in Eclipse console if your Tomcat is integrated with Eclipse or in [tomcat root dir]\logs\localhost.2011-11-15.log otherwise)

Comment: @Andrei Bodnarescu I've added the startup log to the question.

Comment: Right, my bad. Can you please start Tomcat, access your app, get the error, and then give us a snippet of that output?

Comment: @Andrei Bodnarescu The thing is I do not get any stack trace or anything. It just says:     HTTP Status 404 - /dosemem/Start, type Status report, message /dosemem/Start, description The requested resource (/dosemem/Start) is not available. Apache Tomcat/6.0.29. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yep, that's what I ment. Apparently there's not like your application is throwing an error, it's more like it's not deployed. Try exporting it from Eclipse as war (or build it as war any way you like), stop the  Eclipe Tomcat, start tomcat manually from console, and drop the war in the webapps directory, and try it then.

Comment: @Andrei Bodnarescu It's deployed all right and when calling http://localhost:8080/dosemem/Start, logcat entries show that the Start servlet is called. But then it hangs when the database is contacted, but that is not the same problem I suppose. When trying to connect to https://localhost:8443/dosemem/Start it just hangs and there are no logs from the Start servlet.

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning your tomcat from eclipse:
right click in tomcat > clean.
then restart your server